# Height of a point

Tags: normal-distribution

I wonder if there is way to find out the height of a specific point x in a normal distribution whenever the standard deviation is not given.?

Comment: What information have you given?

Comment: @mvw hmm... let say sir that I have $$\frac{2}{\pi} ln (n)$$ as the mean of a normally distributed discrete data,,, but then I want to compute for the standard deviation...but based on the formula of standard deviation it requires every point x to be subtracted from the mean,,, in order to do so... I must know the magnitude (height) of every point x...

Comment: Are you sure it's Normally distributed? if it can't be less than zero, maybe it's a [Rayleigh distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_distribution)

Comment: @Joffan yes sir... with sufficiently large samples at some point it will be...